# Cons of redirecting www to no-www (naked domain name) and vice versa

Tags: redirect

I recently read an article, ["www. is not deprecated"](http://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/), which strongly advices against redirection from www to no-www. I would like to know the main cons of such a redirection and the main cons of redirecting from no-www to www. How would it impact site scalability, search engines visibility, problems with cookies, etc.

Comment: Errr... Doesn't the linked article go through the reasons?

Comment: @BazzaDP, yes it does. However, the questions about redirecting from www to naked domain names are raised constantly here on SO. I am curious to hear the other side.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest something controversial. It doesn't matter. Use either domain.

There are legitimate issues with serving content from a single domain with HTTP 1.1. You have to do domain sharding in order to parallelize content. However browsers only open up 4 connections at the same time, so even that scaling is limited. This is called sharding.

However the issues of sharding are gone with HTTP/2. With HTTP/2 you can parallize assets natively over a single connection. https://http2.github.io/faq/

When you need to scale beyond a single server you'll be faced with other issues, but throwing more hardware at the problem will be the easiest solution. When your site becomes so large you'll want to use a Content Delivery Network at which point, scaling becomes a non-issue for the front end.

There are issues with cross domain cookies. If you do scale to such a large size that you need a single sign on solution, you won't be worried about sub domain cookies, you'll probably be looking at a single sign on service, such as facebook, google, openid, or  you'll roll your own saml2.0 solution, a CDN will also be able to provide a solution to do cross domain cookies as well.

Someone else can speak to authority regarding SEO.

Build your site the way you find aesthetically pleasing, and deal with the scaling issues when you come to them.

Edit: I did think of one advantage of using www.example.com You can cname www, whereas you would not be able to cname the example.com.

Answer (score 1):

Since the article covers the reasons for www domain, I'll not repeat that and look at other side instead:

- It's mostly aesthetic - some people think a bare domain looks better.
- The www isn't needed and some think is a relic of the past - who even differentiates between the World Wide Web and the Internet anymore? Certainly not your browser which is more concerned with the protocol (http/https) than three random letters tacked on to the beginning of a website domain.
- And finally it's extra typing for the user, or speaking - www is actually quite a mouthful when reading out a web address, and don't even come near me with the "dub dub dub" phrasing that some try to use to address this.

Personally I still think www wins it for me - mostly from recognition factor rather than from the technical issues raised in the article (though they help cement this opinion). In the same way that a .com or .country domain is more recognisable as a web address than some of the new TLDs.

Using a subdomain in your website address (of which www is the most recognisable) does have technical advantages as raised in the article - some of which can be worked around - but other than those it's a personal preference so not sure that SO is best place for this since there is no "right" answer.

One thing is clear. You should have one domain variant and stick with it. So redirect to your preferred version (with or without www) so if anyone ends up on the wrong one they are steered right. This just makes sense from a cleanliness point of view and also from an SEO point of view since search engines see the two domains as separate and so you don't want content showing on both as duplicate. Along the same vein, it's best practice to have your webserver listen to both domains to do that redirect and, if using https, to make sure your certificate covers both domains.